# Python iterate over each string?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a string such as:

```
Hello world
```

I'd like to iterate over each character so that the iteration prints:

```
H
He
Hel
Hell
Hello
Hello(space) 
Helllo W... etc
```

How could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just slice it:

```
>>> mystr = 'Hello world'
>>> for i in range(len(mystr)+1):
...     print mystr[:i]
...

H
He
Hel
Hell
Hello
Hello
Hello w
Hello wo
Hello wor
Hello worl
Hello world
>>>
```

Or, a one-line solution:

```
>>> # This might be slower though if the string is massive
>>> print "\n".join([mystr[:i] for i in range(len(mystr)+1)])

H
He
Hel
Hell
Hello
Hello
Hello w
Hello wo
Hello wor
Hello worl
Hello world
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Great answer. Sorry for a badly formulated question.

Comment: @Downvoter - Why was I downvoted?  My code works and the OP said it solved his problem.  What is wrong?

Comment: To avoid copying the string, [`buffer()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#buffer) could be used: `for i in xrange(1, len(s)+1): sys.stdout.write(buffer(s, 0, i)); print`